Cookies are not sent to dev server from localhost even I map it in hosts file
I have frontend application at http://dev-app.company.local and backend at http://dev-app.company.local/backend.
Cookies are working on the dev server, because they are in the same domain. However on localhost the cookies are not sent, which is also understandable as the domains are different.
How can I send cookies from localhost to my backend on http://dev-app.company.local/backend?
P.S: Setting the Cookies header with JS is not an option, the browser removes it
I tried to change the hosts file, mapped my localhost to http://local.dev-app.company.local and http://company.local, while  the backend stays the same, but cookies are not sent to the server
I have changed cookie domain to .dev-app.company.local, but this did not work either.
Maybe there is a way to disable this behavior? It is for development.

This is not possible. It would be a huge security hole if it was. Change your local environment to run both the front and back end.

Hi @RoryMcCrossan , thank you for your reply.
Yes, you are right, but I am looking for a way to turn of this security rule for development purposes only.

I can not run both frontend and backend in the same domain. Backend runs in http:// dev-app.company.local/backend, so I can not run my local frontend app in http:// dev-app.company.local without ngnix. I can do this, but then whole team have to do this, so it is not an option.

I'm afraid you have no alternative
